# Receiving cannot find module error, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
const { getIo } = require('services/socketio');
const restful = require('utils/restful');
const publicApiService = require('services/publicApi');
const accessTokenMiddleware = require('middleware/accessToken');
const validateSessionCookieMiddleware = require('middleware/validateSessionCookie');
const logger = require('utils/logger');
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www",
        ...

}
```

I get this error:

```
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;

^

Error: Cannot find module 'services/socketio'
```

I tried running set NODE_PATH=./lib in terminal but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Check with "services/socketio" path

Comment: If you're implying to write the absolute path i tried that, the next line underneath then gives a similar error and so on.. If i write all of them with their absolute paths then i get the error in another file.

Answer (score 1):

Your local modules should start with `./` - so change it to `'./services/publicApi'`.